# Searching in firebase database returns null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app where I have to fetch the status of a message from the database, but whenever I try to fetch and display data, the app crashes back to home screen.

```
user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
   String uid = user.getUid();
   database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   String msg = textView.getText().toString().trim();
   DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
   myRef.child("Users").child(uid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           for(DataSnapshot db : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
              if(db.getKey().equals(textView.getText().toString().trim())) {
                  count=1;
                  String key = db.getKey();
                  String key2= db.child(key).child("status").getValue(String.class);
                                Toast.makeText(CheckMsg.this,key2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
   }
```

**Database Format**

[image: This is how my database format looks]

Comment: If the app crashes there is going to be an error written to its logcat output. Copy the exact error message and stack trace from there and paste them into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the `key2` statement to

```
String key2= db.child("status").getValue(String.class);
```

OR

```
String key2= dataSnapshot.child(key).child("status").getValue(String.class);
```

`db` is already a child as it is an element of `getChildren()`(like `abc` and all) and you are trying to find a child of `abc` with the name `abc`.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the crash is because `key2` is null:

**In the `for loop`:**

Change this:

```
String key2= db.child(key).child("status").getValue(String.class);
```

to this:

```
String key2= db.child("status").getValue(String.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

After Reading your Details Provided.

Issues-
1) Update the key as
       String `key2=db.child("status").getValue(String.class);`

Try this. If this doesn't Work, comment below...